# Ignore serialize some object fields at runtime (Dynamic Ignore)

Tags: c#

I have a webmethod which return an object ASResponse :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public ASResponse test()
    {
         return new ASResponse ();
     }
```

Question :

Is it possible to customize the SOAP response by force the compiler do not serialize some ASResponse class fields ( if some condition are true) and allow them if some condition are false.

Samples :

```
<soap:Body>
```

`<WrongCaseResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org">`

```
<WrongCaseResult>

<Length>5</Length>

<ID>125487</ID>

<Error>183</Error>

</WrongCaseResult>

</WrongCaseResponse>

</soap:Body>
```

==========================================================================

```
   <soap:Body>
    <SuccessCaseResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
  <SuccessCaseResult>
        <Length>5</Length>
        <ID>125487</ID>
        <CallHome>5000</CallHome>
  </SuccessCaseResult>
</SuccessCaseResponse >
 </soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the question correctly you want to hide properties if 'some condition' is true or false. The already mentioned XmlIgnoreAttribute will always exclude a property from serialization. If you are looking for a way to determine at runtime if you want to include or exclude a property have a look at the ShouldSerialize method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Small example:

```
[XmlElement("visibility")]
public bool? Visibility { get; set; }
public bool ShouldSerializeVisibility() { return Visibility.HasValue; }
```

Comment: I'll take a look, but i think you have totally undestand what i'am expecting

Comment: Thanks Eddy, it works at 50% of my expectation now i have o found out how hide those fields from sample SOAP 1.1 request and response for the end user

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [`XmlIgnoreAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx)? Put this on your property and XML serialization will ignore it.

I'm not terribly hot on SOAP serialization, so it could be that you actually need [`SoapIgnoreAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.soapignoreattribute.aspx) instead... I can't honestly say I know the difference between them, but hopefully giving you both options, you'll be able to take it further :)

Answer (score 0):

Yup, mark the Properties you would like to ignore with `[XmlIgnore]`

Of course, if you have control over the ASResponse class (sorry i don't know very well the API)

-- EDIT

Sorry now I understood correctly the question. I don't know how to dynamicaly define it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define some default values and it prevents the fields from being serialized. But it works only with XmlSerializer

```
[XmlElement, DefaultValue("")]
string data;

[XmlArray, DefaultValue(null)]
List<string> data;
```